# WPF Marquee Text Animation in restriced space

Tags: c#, wpf, text, marquee

*I can scroll text with [DoubleAnimation] but 
     I'd like to show as follows:*

1.I have big Grid and small Canvas

2.Text is appeared in canvas right edge

3.Test is disappeared in canvas left edge

4.I like to show text in only canvas. not grid

how to make this in C#?

this is image link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmhho.jpg

*1. C# code*

```
private void animation()
    {

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

        DoubleAnimation moveLeft = new DoubleAnimation();
        moveLeft.From = Canvas.Width;
        moveLeft.To = -tbxText.Width;
        moveLeft.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        moveLeft.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(moveLeft, tbxText);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveLeft, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
        moveLeft.EasingFunction = new CircleEase() { EasingMode = System.Windows.Media.Animation.EasingMode.EaseOut };
        sb.Children.Add(moveLeft);
        sb.Begin();

    }
```

*2. xaml Code*

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="59" Margin="42,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" Background="#FFC9F594">
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="59" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255">
            <TextBox x:Name="tbxText" Height="34" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Test Test Test Test" Canvas.Top="6" Width="196" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="20"/>
        </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is good way

Panel.ZIndex="1"

```
<Grid Panel.ZIndex="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="114,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266">
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="59" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" Margin="1,0,0,-4">
            <TextBox x:Name="tbxText" Height="34" Canvas.Left="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Test Test Test Test" Canvas.Top="6" Width="196" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="20"/>
        </Canvas>
</Grid>
```